# AngularJS/WebAPI Image upload using API wrong result

Tags: asp.net, json, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am looking to use Deviantsart's public API in order to host some images for a project I am working on.

The issue I am having is I am not getting the JSON result back with the URL but instead getting the entire webpage.

their instructions are relatively simple

> Upload using our public REST API: POST http://deviantsart.com yourimage.jpg
>
> Then returns a JSON-Result with the URL:

```
{ "url" : "urltoimage" }
```

**Here is my code.**

**WebAPI**

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadGliderData()
    {
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }
        var httpPostedFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["file"];
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var content =
                new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                var image = new Bitmap(httpPostedFile.InputStream);
                var stream = new MemoryStream();
                image.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                var imgContent = new StreamContent(stream);
                imgContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("image/jpeg");
                content.Add(imgContent);
               
                using (
                   var message =
                       await client.PostAsync("http://deviantsart.com", content))
                {
                    var input = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, input);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**AngularJS Controller**

```
function upload(files) {
    if (files && files.length) {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];
            Upload.upload({
                url: '/api/SGWebAPI/UploadGliderData',
                method: 'POST',
                data: $scope.glider,
                file: file
            })
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                debugger;
                console.log('file ' + config.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + data);
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                debugger;
                console.log('error status: ' + status);
            });
        }
    }
```

**Result**

The value for input can be found [Here](http://pastebin.com/xsMsSDLK)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Maybe it isn't posting as multi-part form data so you are hitting that first if block, but you aren't returning from it so it continues to process.  Seems like you need a return statement for the UnsupportedMediaType.  Might not be your problem but if you get that response type afterwards at least you narrowed down what might be happening.

Comment: Why even post to your api to post to theirs? Just change your javascript URL to theirs.

Comment: @JeffTreuting Thank you for your comment, just checked and I am not hitting the first IF statement therefore it is posting as multi-part form data

Comment: @acastr7 I tried doing that and I kept getting this error.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://deviantsart.com/. Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

I tried a number of things but to no anvil.